# Is it possible to tweak a hard disk drive’s firmware? A hard drive from a satellite decoder cannot be mounted on a PC

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, external-drive

Is it possible to install/replace a hard disk drive’s firmware with a customized firmware that makes the hard disk drive be read by certain devices only?

I have a hard drive that reads on a satellite decoder but when I connect it to my computer, it makes a sound that something has been connected but the drive is not visible anywhere. Is there a fix for that or the drive is just encrypted to stop end users from manipulating it ?

Comment: This sounds like an “[XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).” The reality is the majority of hard disk drive firmware is proprietary and closed source; unless you have the tools (software and possibly hardware) to get into that firmware, chances are slim to none that you will be able to do anything with that firmware. But when you say, “…that makes the hard disk drive be read by certain devices only?” What is your actual goal? Because what you describe sounds like a job better suited for full disk encryption.

Comment: I have a Hard Drive that reads on a satellite decorder but when I connect it to my computer, it makes a sound that something has been connected but the Drive is not visible anywhere. Is there a fix for that or the Drive is just encrypted to stop end users from manipulating it ?

Comment: Not all hard drives are meant to be used in all circumstances.  Some can sort-of work, for instance, Security Camera recorder hard drives like Western Digital Purple can usually be plugged into a regular computer.  But they are quickly worn out if used for general purposes.  I don't know what make/model of hard drive you have, but it might not be usable for your computer.

Comment: @NailTsakatsa , it's best to ask the question regarding the actual goal you have, and have details that people can actually use.  For instance, your original question doesn't mention what OS you're using, but answers for Windows would be very different from other OSes.  Including the make and model of the hard drive would help identify the problem.  It would also help to say what you're trying to do ("My satellite decoder broke but I have some movies saved on it").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the solution. I was trying to connect a Hitachi 500GB (3.0Gb/s) Hard Drive to my PC (using Windows 7). The challenge I was facing was that the computer would notify that something was connected but wouldn't display the drive in Computer. The SOLUTION was that I opened the Disk Management Utility (<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> -> then type `diskmgmt.msc` -> press <kbd>Enter</kbd>). The drive would showed as being unallocated, so I allocated the drive and then formatted it and I was ready to go.

I would like to thank you all for your support and contributions.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, yes - but HDD firmware is not open source and the work involved to re-write firmware would be enormous. Far better off utilising full disk encryption and keeping an index of the keys.